# Bootstrap datepicker issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am having some datepicker issues

html

```
<div class="input-append date" id="dp1" data-date="" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" style="display:inline;">
    <input size="10" type="text" value="">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div> to
<div class="input-append date" id="dp2" data-date="" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" style="display:inline;">
    <input size="10" type="text" value="">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

js

```
$('#dp1').datepicker({ orientation: 'auto bottom', autoclose:true });

$('#dp2').datepicker();
```

1) the calendar pop up insists on popping on top of the text field not bottom
2) the selected date is not highlighted

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently for the bootstrap date picker the property 'bottom' means 'top' and vice-versa. I found the [bug posted on Git Hub](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/1035) It seems all you have to do is this:

```
$('#dp1').datepicker({ orientation: 'auto top', autoclose:true });
```

and it will show below the text field. As for the highlighting issue it [shows correctly in my JS.Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y8xh8rxt/) as long as you first select a date. If this doesnt work for you maybe you have a JS error in your console?

Hope that helps.